# Cleanest way to initialize string outside of conditional statement where it's assigned?

Tags: c#, variables

```
string str = ""
if(something) {
  str = "a"
} else {
  str = "b"
}
```

Is this the cleanest way? or is there a better way to expose the str outside of conditional scope without this dirty empty string initialization

Comment: "Clean" is subjective. There are tools you can use like ternary operators and pattern matching, but it's up to you to decide what is right for your code.

Comment: I m not too sure if theres any other way around it, but if you really want it to look better you could opt to use a ternary operator to replace the if-else statement

Comment: I would use the ternary operation myself, but another way is to assign it the default value first, and then reassign it in a single `if` statement: `string str = "b"; if (something) str = "a";`

Answer (score 2):

you could set it using a ternary operator in a single line. Something like

```
string str = something ? "a" : "b";
```